Unity InputSystem: Android GamePad Shoulder Button Also Triggers Keyboard Input Signal
While using Unity's Input System to handle GamePad inputs, I’ve noticed that pressing the GamePad shoulder buttons (e.g., L1/R1) simultaneously triggers a Keyboard input signal (e.g., a keyboard key is detected as "pressed"). This behavior causes input handling issues in my game.
What I Have Tried:
Checked the Input System configuration to ensure there are no mapping errors.
Tested on different Android devices, but the issue persists.
Updated to the latest version of Unity and Input System, but the issue remains unresolved.
Additional Information:
Device settings and drivers are updated to the latest versions.
No other input devices are connected at the same time.
I hope that when using a gamepad on Android, the pressed buttons do not get mapped to the keyboard.

Can you share your input handling codes please? Also please describe the control scheme of your game more detailed. Are you trying to add multiple controller types or trying to use them at same time? Also please share your input system's screenshot please.
